# Constructing a Numerical Method

Tags: numerical-methods

I need to construct an 3 step order 3 explicit and order 4 implicit method using order conditions, such that they have the characteristic:

$\rho(\omega)=\omega(\omega^2 -1)$

I've figured out the explicit method by solving a system to find $\sigma(\omega)$ which ended up being:

$y_{n+3}-y_{n+1}=1/3h(f_{n+2}+4f_{n+1}+f_n)$

However since the step size is 3. How do I produce the coefficient for the $f_{n+3}$ term for the implicit method???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explicit method you've provided is not of the third order. In fact its order is first.

Recall the definition of the characteristic polynomials. For the linear multistep method
$$
y_{n+s} + \sum_{k = 0}^{s-1} a_k y_{n + k} = 
h \sum_{k=0}^{s} b_k f_{n + k}
$$
the polynomials are [defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_multistep_method#Consistency_and_order) as
$$
\rho(\omega) = \omega^s + \sum_{k=0}^{s-1} a_k \omega^k\\
\sigma(\omega) = \sum_{k=0}^{s} b_k \omega^k.
$$
In term of the polynomials the order condition is
$$
\rho(e^h) - h\sigma(e^h) = O(h^{p+1}).
$$
Since $a_0 = 0, a_1 = -1, a_2 = 0$ we have
$$
\rho(e^h) = e^h(e^{2h} - 1) = 
2h + 4h^2 + \frac{13}{3}h^3 + \frac{10}{3}h^4 + O(h^5)\\
\sigma(e^h) = \sum_{k=0}^3 b_k + h\sum_{k=0}^3 kb_k
+\frac{h^2}{2} \sum_{k=0}^3 k^2b_k
+\frac{h^3}{6} \sum_{k=0}^3 k^3b_k
+ O(h^4).
$$
To get an explicit method ($b_3$ = 0) of the third order one needs to solve
$$
b_0 + b_1 + b_2 = 2\\
b_1 + 2 b_2 = 4\\
b_1 + 4 b_2 = \frac{26}{3}.
$$
The solution is
$$
b_0 = \frac{1}{3},
\quad
b_1 = -\frac{2}{3},
\quad
b_2 = \frac{7}{3}.
$$
$$
y_{n+3} - y_{n+1} = \frac{h}{3}\left(
7f_{n+2} - 2f_{n+1} + f_{n}
\right).
$$
To get the implicit method of the fourth order we need to solve the system
$$
b_0 + b_1 + b_2 + b_3 = 2\\
b_1 + 2 b_2 + 3 b_3 = 4\\
b_1 + 4 b_2 + 9 b_3 = \frac{26}{3}\\
b_1 + 8 b_2 + 27 b_3 = 20
$$
The solution is
$$
b_0 = 0, \quad
b_1 = \frac{1}{3}, \quad
b_2 = \frac{4}{3}, \quad
b_3 = \frac{1}{3}.
$$
$$
y_{n+3} - y_{n+1} = \frac{h}{3}\left(
f_{n+3} + 4 f_{n+2} + f_{n+1}
\right).
$$
Note the method looks like the one you've provided, but is shifted by one. Formally, I would not call this method a three-step method, since $a_0 = b_0 = 0$ and the method is effectively a two-step method.

Comment: I think we may be using differing "order conditions". Maybe not. In class we use the formula: $$\sum_{m=0}^{ s}m^ka_m=k\sum_{m=0}^{s}m^{k-1}b_m$$

Comment: I see they are the same. I was not taking $b_3=0$ when doing the explicit method. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Should the fourth equation for the implicit scheme should that be equal to 20 instead?

Comment: @sjf2468 exactly, that is $6\frac{10}{3}$